# Connecting /home from separate drive after fresh installation

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive

I had my system set up with / on one drive and /home on another. The / drive has died and I was forced to reinstall the system onto a new drive and I reinstalled it without it being aware of the other drive with /home. I would like now to add the /home from the other drive to be used as /home in a new installation.

Currently there are different users on both (ie during the fresh installation I set up a different user to the one that is on /home). There is only one user in each drive. In principle I don't mid re-installing the / again if necessary to connect the /home from the other drive.

What is the proper way to do it? (This is the closest question to mine but there is no answer there... [Adding home directory from old drive to fresh install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/852096/adding-home-directory-from-old-drive-to-fresh-install))

Comment: Detailled instructions here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving

Comment: Thanks, but not quite - I have tried that but ended up not being able to login (my username shows up on a login page but when I enter my password the screen goes black and then back to the login page (there is no note about password being incorrect or anything like that)).

Comment: Login loops are usually a separate problem. Don't confuse or conflate the two.

Comment: Ah, so I just swapped one issue for another... except I used to be able to login :-| Let the googling commence...

Comment: Could be that your user ID # on the old system doesn't match the # on the new system.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I solved it in an ugly way. After I followed with @vanadium's advice and got stuck in the login loop, and no solutions I could found worked, I set up a second user in the system, logged in as that user, deleted my original user and recreated it from scratch. Then I logged in again as that newly created user and everything was fine.

Thanks everyone for suggestions!